# Using linked sources with Android projects

Tags: android

I need to use a java source file in two my Android projects (Eclipse Helios 3.6.1). The source file (let's name it "library") contains a public class with public routines, it does not use any resources. I placed the library file in a separate directory from both projects.

To include the library in each project, I added the folder with the library to Project properties \ Java Build Path \ Source \ Link Source. The library was added to the project tree, but compiler forced me to remove "package" declaration from the library, which is OK for me.

The problem is that I don't know how to reference the library from the projects sources. Which namespace should be used? What should be placed in "import" clause? I seached a lot, but found nothing helpful (may be I used a wrong key words for the search).

The library excerpt (no "package" clause at the beginning!):

```
public class Misc {
    public static void myRoutine() {
    }
}
```

A project code (no "import" clause):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public onEvent() {
        myRoutine();
        Misc.myRoutine();
    }
}
```

Compiler does not allow me to use myRoutine() nor Misc.myRoutine(). Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and best way is to set up the classes you want to re-use as a [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) in Eclipse and then add a reference to it in your project on the Android tab in Properties.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With a library project I need to make the library classes derived from Activity. Also, I need to declare the activities in the manifest (and then deploy two apk together?). This sound as a big overhead... But, seems, I need to follow your answer.

Comment: No you can just create a simple class that doesn't extend anything. No need to extend an Activity or put anything in the manifest.

Comment: Really? Compiler does not report any errors, but I'm getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception at runtime. I have to check my code again. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: According to the link you gave about library project "a library project's manifest file must declare all of the shared components". But there is no definition clause for a convenient class in the manifest file, is not it? [manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: That just means anything you would normally declare in an application's manifest.xml needs to also be declared in a library's manfiest, meaning Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver classes.

Comment: You are totally correct. It works fine for me now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First, you  should not remove the package declaration. Second, you should be able to compile this class into a jar and add it in the way you mentioned above. Everything else failing you should be able to create a separate project in Eclipse for this and make this new library project a dependency for your main project. Try these options, then it should work.

Comment: I cannot leave package declaration. The compiler says 'The declared package blablabla does not match the expected package ""'. Using jar, as I understand, force me to manually maintain jar updates every time library source changed. I will try to use a library project, although it is a bit overcomplicated. Thank you.